# How high is sympathy for Israel among Bolsonaro's supporters and/or Brazilian Evangelicals?

Tags: israel, religion, public-opinion, brazil

An [article](https://mondediplo.com/2019/09/13netanyahu) in *Le Monde Diplomatique* claims that:

> Like Trump, Bolsonaro is highly dependent on his nation’s politically powerful Evangelical community, and they are Israel one-hundred percenters. [...]  The Brazilians honored the Israeli in a weirdly appropriate fashion, by lighting up its famous Christ the Redeemer statue in blue and white, like the Israeli flag. The Israeli leader also held an emotional meeting with Brazilian evangelicals: ‘We have no better friends in the world than the evangelical community, and the evangelical community has no better friend in the world than Israel,’ Netanyahu told them. ‘You are our brothers and sisters.’

Are there polls (in Brazil) backing up this analogy, i.e. how sympathetic to Israel are Bolsonaro's supporters and/or Brazilian Evangelicals?

Comment: Are you working on a university thesis or something?

Comment: @JohnK: no, but I've basically suggested this question to me when you answered with Orban to my other question (about Europe). A quick search found the theory laid out (as you can see) and it's a bit more plausible because of the Evangelical element (lacking in Hungary). But even this one [about Bolosonar's supproters] still seems short of clear empirical evidence, at least in English (It seems Pew doesn't poll Latin America much.)

Comment: I think you will find that the Israel thing has evolved into a secular Liberal/Conservative split pretty much everywhere you go, with evangelicals just a minor subset, although the width of the split varies with country. In Canada, Conservatives are more supportive than the Liberal/NDP and there is no direct religious component at all that I can see. In UK, same thing but a wider split; Labour has been scandalized recently by anti-semetism charges by the party's jewish faction, and Corbyn's open support for Hamas/Hezb is no secret.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any polls, but a (definitely non-scientific) research shows some evidence of that:

1. Searching for [evangelicos israel](https://www.google.com/search?q=evangelicos%20israel) shows many links to Brazilian articles that claim evangelicals are in fact sympathetic to Israel. I understand this is circular to what you asked in the first place, but at least shows that in Brazil's mainstream media there is this same perception.
2. Among the [top 10 evangelical churches](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_denomina%C3%A7%C3%B5es_protestantes_no_Brasil_por_n%C3%BAmero_de_membros) in Brazil by the number of followers, I could find pro-Israel texts on three of their sites ([Universal](https://www.google.com/search?q=israel%20site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.universal.org), [Quadrangular](https://www.google.com/search?q=israel%20site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.portalbr4.com.br) and [Deus é Amor](https://www.google.com/search?q=israel%20site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.ipda.com.br)). While the majority doesn't seem to display support to Israel, these three churches are considered very influential. In particular, Universal owns a prominent TV channel.
3. This [paper](https://www.academia.edu/download/51790310/Artigo.pdf) claims that Brazilian evangelical congress members show support of Israel in their discourses. The study came before Bolsonaro's mandate, but is another evidence that Brazilian evangelicals do like Israel.